# Inefficient Planetary Administration Influence Modifier

Tags: stellaris

I noticed that I had a negative influence modifier called 'Inefficient Planetary Administration' that was applying a -10% penalty.

I did **not** have more core world planets than I should have. After a while this modifier disappeared without me making any conscious decisions to get rid of it.

My question is what causes this negative influence modifier to appear in the first place?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is because of having too many core planets. A planet which is in the colonization process (i.e. where you still pay 8 energy upkeep and cannot build yet) also counts towards the core limit, even if it isn't shown.

If you colonize a world while at your core planet limit and then add it to a sector it will usually stay your core world until the process is completed and incur the penalty.

I've also had a bug, where such a world incurred the penalty indefinetely and I had to remove and add it to the sector again to get rid of it.

So, if possible add a system to a sector before colonizing it, if not removing and readding the planet to the sector should fix it immediately.

Comment: I thought the planets during colonization don't get added to the max core planets counter until they've fully settled or is that what you mean when you say "also counts towards the core limit, even if it isn't shown."?

Comment: @S.Wessels Correct, but they still count. Assume you are at 5/5 core planets. Colonize a planet, you'll still be at 5/5 core planets, but you'll take a 10% penalty for inefficient administration. So it is added to the core planets right after colonizing, it's just not shown in the interface.

Comment: I didn't know that. +1

Comment: You can also clear the bug by saving and reloading. This doesn't cost influence. I haven't had the bug occur since I increased my core planets to 6, even when I had 6 core planets and colonies settling in.